# erroer while installing pl/java postgresql

Tags: postgresql, pljava

I am trying to install **pljava** in my Linux system.
the below is my command and error

```
   root@pega-5-instance:/etc/postgresql/9.1/share/pljava# su postgres -c "/usr/bin/psql -d             pegadb -f /etc/postgre
    sql/9.1/share/pljava/install.sql"<br>
    CREATE SCHEMA<br>
    GRANT<br>
    psql:/etc/postgresql/9.1/share/pljava/install.sql:6: ERROR:  could not access file      "pljava": No such file or directory
```

I have installed java 64bit and pljava 64 bit.

please help me to solve the  problem.